# Factory returning generic interface

Tags: java, generics, factory

I have a `TemplateEngine` interface whose implementations would be `MoustacheTemplateEngine`, `FreemarkerTemplateEngine` etc.

```
public interface TemplateEngine<T> {
    public T compileTemplate(String templateStr);
    public void merge(T t, Map<String, Object> data);
    public String getTemplateLang();
}
```

The purpose of `compileTemplate` method is to enable caching of compiled templates.

Here is an implementation example:

```
import com.github.mustachejava.Mustache;

public class MoustacheTemplateEngine implements TemplateEngine<Mustache> {

    @Override
    public Mustache compileTemplate(String templateStr) {
        // return compiled template;
    }

    @Override
    public void merge(Mustache compiledTemplate, Map<String, Object> data) {
        // merge
    }

    @Override
    public String getTemplateLang() {
        return "moustache";
    }
}
```

I wish to create a factory that returns a `TemplateEngine` depending on the template language supplied. **The factory, and the client that would use the factory, do not know anything about `TemplateEngine` implementations**.

```
public class TemplateEngineFactory {

    private Map<String, TemplateEngine<?>> TEMPLATE_ENGINE_REGISTRY = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Scan all TemplateEngine impls in classpath and populate registry
    }

    public TemplateEngine<?> getTemplateEngine(String templateLang) {
        return TEMPLATE_ENGINE_REGISTRY.get(templateLang);
    }

}
```

A client would use the factory as below.

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("name", "Tom");
TemplateEngine<?> templateEngine = factory.getTemplateEngine("moustache");
Object compiledTemplate = templateEngine.compileTemplate("Hi {{name}}");
templaeEngine.merge(compiledTemplate, data); // compile error
```

The error being `The method merge(capture#3-of ?, Map<String,Object>) in the type TemplateEngine<capture#3-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Map<String,Object>)`.

I understand the error and I know my API design is flawed due to the use of wildcard in factory. My question is how to design a factory for such use case and avoid unsafe casts?

Comment: Why don't you type your `TemplateEngineFactory` ? So when you instanciate  some of the implementation you want, instead of using a wildcard, you wouldn't have any trouble calling any method of your `TemplateEngine`.

Comment: Maybe you should consider hiding concrete template implementation (e.g. `Moustache`) behind a common interface as well?

Comment: @yegodm yes but that does not solve the problem as I want to avoid type-casting the compiled template in `merge` method.

Comment: Maybe you can delegate `merge()` to that interface as well?

Comment: @yegodm I'll still have to use an unsafe cast at some point until I get the generics right.

Comment: But you won't need to keep `TemplateEngine` generic. `TemplateEngine` produces you one of `Template` instances based on the selected language. That concrete implementation knows how to `merge(Map<String, Object> data)`.

Comment: @yegodm `merge` method accepts a `Template` so that clients can cache templates after calling `compileTemplate` only once per template and supply compiled templates from cache.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner then `CompiledTemplate` interface should have methods like `setRawTemplate` and `getRawTemplate` since `MoustacheTemplateEngine.merge` requires the raw template. This again means either I use generic type or code with `Object` and type-cast in `merge` method, e.g. `if(compiledTemplate.getRawTemplate() instanceof Mustache) { Mustache m = (Mustache) compiledTemplate.getRawTemplate(); }` where `Mustache` is `com.github.mustachejava.Mustache`.

Comment: @Somu Then use `Vistor` pattem where `CompiledTemplate` visits a `TemplateEngine`. Let your template select the proper logic in the engine. For example, invocation chain might look like this: `engine.merge(CompiledTemplate t, data) -> t.merge(engine, data) -> engine.mergeMoustache(t, data)`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to put an *unsafe* cast at some point. The best option would be,

```
public <T> TemplateEngine<T> getTemplateEngine(String templateLang) {
    return (TemplateEngine<T>) TEMPLATE_ENGINE_REGISTRY.get(templateLang);
}
```

And then you can call it like,

```
TemplateEngine<Mustache> templateEngine = factory.getTemplateEngine("moustache");
```

Comment: This is what i meant with my comment on the question, I did similar things on some projects, and it works really well

Comment: Isn't there a better way to design the factory so that I can avoid unsafe cast completely?

Comment: Also, this means a client needs to know about implementation details (in this case `Mustache` class) to use the factory. This is a no go for me.

Comment: There is no way to know exactly what type if `TemplateEngine` client is asking for. Pass `Class` as argument and do `class.cast`. This at least gets rid of warning and gives you more flexibility to handle what type caller code is asking for.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the wildcard, replace this:

`TemplateEngine<?> templateEngine = factory.getTemplateEngine("moustache");`

to this:

`TemplateEngine templateEngine = factory.getTemplateEngine("moustache");`.

You don't need to explicit the wildcard when you call the factory to get the `TemplateEngine` you want.

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: This would give type safety warning

Comment: I know it's a bad smell, but he doesn't have a class hierarchy. So, he can use it anyway.